# What's the meaning of “snapped” in “she snapped harder than ever”?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Who can explain me what is the meaning of this quote “she snapped harder than ever”? I’m Portuguese. I can’t understand what is “snapped”.

Comment: Please be sure to include more details in your posts, like the source of the quote, the surrounding context, and your own research. Otherwise, your post might be closed. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.

Comment: See [definition 2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snap): *to utter sharp biting words : bark out irritable or peevish retorts*.  In other words, *"respond in an irritable manner"*.

Comment: Are we talking about a person or a female snapping turtle? The meaning would be slightly different depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

Definition by Merriam-Webster:

> to give way suddenly under emotional stress or strain

Imagine this...

You're talking with your wife (If you don't have one, imagine you do. Boom! You're no longer single!). You've been making her upset for a while, bit by bit. Now you just said something to make her REALLY angry. That was *the last straw*. She **snaps**! She gets SUPER ANGRY and starts yelling at you. You've made her snap several times before, but this time, she gets angrier than ever before. **She snapped harder than ever!**

So yeah... *she* just **snapped** and got really upset and angry after a lot of anger has built up for a while.